# Python script fails when submitted to PBS

Tags: python, cluster

I'm trying to submit a simple python script to PBS using the command:

```
qsub -l procs=1 -q copperhead test.py, but the command fails with the error file (i.e., test.py.e--) saying:

/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1339901.cph-m1.uncc.edu.SC: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/1339901.cph-m1.uncc.edu.SC: line 3: `with open('a.out','w') as f:'
```

The contents of test.py is:

```
with open('a.out','w') as f:
        pass
```

First, I run `module load anaconda5` which installs conda version 4.6.14 and python 3.6.7. When I just run `python test.py`, it works. When I submit the "test.py" in a shell script to PBS, it works. But the "test.py" fails to execute when submitted directly to PBS.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? And please edit the question to format the quote as such.

Comment: Hi

It is Python 3.6.7